# Studying the hardness of polynomial-time approximability using the concept of stability of approximation

Tags: approximation-algorithms, optimization, approximation-hardness

In the Conclusion section, the author of [this paper "Stability of Approximation Algorithms for Hard Optimization Problems" by Juraj Hromkovič, 1999](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-47849-3_2) claims that

> Using the notion of stability one can search for a spectrum of the hardness of a problem according to the set of inputs. For instance, considering a hard problem like TSP one could get an infinite sequence of input languages $L_0, L_1, L_2, \ldots$ given by some distance measure, where $\epsilon_r(n)$ is the best achievable relative error for the language $L_r$.

As I understand, the notion of stability of approximation is relative to a specific problem $Q$ (e.g., TSP above), a specific approximation algorithm for some subproblem of $Q_0$ (corresponding to $L_0$ above), and a specific distance measure. Given that, how can we construct a spectrum of the hardness of of problem $Q$ according to their polynomial-time approximability? Specifically, how to show that "$\epsilon_r(n)$ is the best achievable relative error for the language $L_r$" using the concept of stability of approximation?

Concrete examples are appreciated.